# How can I take out an object from an image to remove the background?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a uint8 image and a mask of it (float32).

The mask has ones where the object I want to keep is, and zeros for the background.

I want to make a new image that shows the real colored object instead of the ones, and keep the background zeros.

I tried to multiply both images but it says that the mask has 3 dimensions and the colored image 4 dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an RGBA image, which may be converted to 3-channel rgb/bgr via `cv2.cvtColor()` function. Also i believe that it would be more clear to do masking with `cv2.bitwise_and()`.